# Make an api write a post request to a file

Tags: node.js

I wandered if there is a way to make a browser make a post request to an api who then appends that message to a file ? If so how would I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in method `fetch`.

So for example you want to make a request to `http://localhost:3000/test` with the body `testing` you can write it like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/test", { method: 'POST', data: 'testing' })
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(res => { /* Do whatever you want with the response */ });
```

You can read more about this method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch